# Putting a ListFragment inside a DialogFragment?

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, android-dialogfragment, android-listfragment

I have a DialogFragment fragment that shows up just fine. It has some text/pictures/buttons up at the top of the fragment, but in the lower half, I want a listview (or I suppose, a ListFragment).

I've already created the class (which extends ListFragment) and its adapter and everything. How do I get this list to show up at the bottom of the DialogFragment?

I tried adding this to my .xml defining my DialogFragment layout:

```
<fragment
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/nested_listfragment"
                class="com.aruka.myapp.NameOfClassExtendingListFragment"
                />
```

Comment: have you created your own dialog layout and inflate it already to your dialog fragment class? please show us the classes you made

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a custom layout for your dialog fragment and put the ListFragment into it.

[Here](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Using-DialogFragment) is a good resource about DialogFragments if you want to learn more.

**Update for the Exception:**

From [Android Documentation](http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.2.html#NestedFragments). You should inflate the ListFragment programatically.

> Note: You cannot inflate a layout into a fragment when that layout
>   includes a . Nested fragments are only supported when added
>   to a fragment dynamically.

Comment: I tried putting the ListFragment inside it but it crashes after a while because it has errors inflating

Comment: That's most likely because of the stuff that's going on inside the ListFragment. Can you post the stack trace ?

Comment: I posted the fragment XML code I used to include the ListFragment inside the DialogFragment

Comment: that looks good. Can you also post the class extending ListFragment itself ?

Comment: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Binary XML file line #99: Duplicate id 0x7f0e0094, tag null, or parent id 0xffffffff with another fragment

Comment: Is this because the list itself is using an ID of "@android:id/list" while I am already using "@android:id/list" for another list one level beneath the DialogFragment?

Comment: How do I inflate it programmatically in my Dialog?

Comment: I see in your link lines like "transaction.add(R.id.video_fragment, videoFragment).commit();" but I don't know what my corresponding R id would be if I am doing this programmatically and not in XML.

Comment: It should be the container ID. Create a frame layout in XML and use its id.

Comment: So in my dialogfragment XML, include something like `<FrameLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/listfragment_container"
                />` where I want the list to show up?

Comment: Throwing error "Fragment does not have a view", but no line number or reference to which activity/fragment/etc this refers to

Comment: You need to inflate a view in onCreateView and return it

Comment: None of this is working, unfortunately, I need some kind of example because this is all horribly confusing